# Grails query based on Date

Tags: grails, grails-orm, criteria

imagine I have this domain class:

```
class Event {

    DateTime startDate
    DateTime endDate
}
```

I want to find Events that ended in the last 15 to 30 minutes.
I would like to have something like:

```
def now = DateTime.now()

def events= Event.withCriteria {
    ge("endDate".plusMinutes(15), now)
    ge("endDate".plusMinutes(30), now)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it also with plain Date magic

```
def events= Event.withCriteria {
  between "endDate", new Date( now.time - 30 * 60 * 1000 ), new Date( now.time - 15 * 60 * 1000 )
}
```